# golang & mongo: How to implement Zeroer interface

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to figure out how to implement `bsoncoded.Zeroer` interface.

These is my straightforward struct:

```go
type WorkContract struct {
    ID           primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Code         string             `bson:"code,omitempty"`
}

func (m *WorkContract) IsZero() bool {
    log.Println("zero called")
    return len(m.Code) == 0
}
```

I've tried to implement `bsoncodec.Zeroer` interface.

Nevertheless, this is never reached.

My repository's `SaveNew` method is:

```go
func (repository *WorkContractRepository) SaveNew(ctx context.Context, workContract *model.WorkContract) (*model.WorkContract, error) {
    result, err := repository.mongoCollection.InsertOne(ctx, workContract)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    if oid, ok := result.InsertedID.(primitive.ObjectID); ok {
        modelWorkContract.ID = oid
    } else {
        //TODO Handle it, probably ignore it
        // Not objectid.ObjectID, do what you want
    }

    return workContract, nil
}
```

I don't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the struct type must implement `Zeroer`, not a pointer to it: `func (m WorkContract) IsZero() bool`. But if you're already using a pointer, just use a `nil` pointer value to indicate zero.

Comment: @Jordi the `IsZero` method is invoked only for the encoded struct's fields (if their types implement the `Zeroer` interface). So if you're storing `WorkContract` directly, its `IsZero` method will NOT be used. But if you are storing some other struct, one that has a field of type `WorkContract`, then the `IsZero` method will be invoked. And note that the field type's method set must include the `IsZero` method for it to satisfy the `Zeroer` interface, if you define the method with a pointer receiver then that method will not be included in the non-pointer type's method set.